# How do I query nested object by property inside an array?

Tags: lokijs

I have a collection of several thousand (potentially 30-40k) documents, with a structure (greatly simplified) like this:

```
{
 propA:'123',
 obj: [
       {prop1:'a'},
       {prop1:'b'},
       {prop1:'c'}
 ],
 propB:456
}
```

How can I query to find all documents where `obj.prop1==='b'`?  I can't seem to figure out how to check a property of an object inside an array property.
This is using version 1.5.1.

Thanks!

**Update**
Resolved - see my answer...

Comment: Not sure why this is flagged as a bad question...can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: ridiculous that his question was given negative votes. It is a perfectly legit question, and the poster's answer helped me as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I needed to include the nested property name in quotes in my query. The query example I tried in Mongo does actually work in Loki if you include the object.propName in quotes, so this DOES work: `myCollection.find( { "obj.prop1": "b" } )`

Comment: I'm confused, this is the exact same syntax you mention in `Update` of the question where you say it doesn't work...?

Comment: Had same question ... I confirm this does work (in lokijs 1.5.12)!!

Comment: @GabeO'Leary, I just edited the question in order to remove all confusion and stop people from down voting the it (probably due to this issue). I have validated that it does work. I have upvoted this answer, and upvoted the question after edit. Hope it helps to clarify things.