# querying `lokidb` for keys in array that match a pattern

Tags: lokijs

I am playing around with `Lokijs` to figure out if it will work for me. I have created a db of about 170K records (~500 MB size). The records have (among other keys), the following

```
…
authors: [
    {name: 'William Shakespeare'},
    {name: 'Ed McBain'},
    {name: 'Odom Shatner'},
    …
],
…
```

How do I query for all the records that have the string `/m Sha/`? I have tried (the obviously wrong)

```
const results = coll.find({
     'authors': {
           'name': {
               '$regex': /m Sha/ 
           }
     }
});
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer at [How do I query nested object by property inside an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48414562/how-do-i-query-nested-object-by-property-inside-an-array?rq=1)

The following does the job

```
const results = coll.find({
    'authors.name': {
        '$regex': /m Sha/ 
    }
});
```